# GAC (gacutil) not working with IronPython.dll on Mono

Tags: mono, ironpython

I tried to use gacutil (mono) for IronPython, but I got the following error.

```
sudo gacutil -i IronPython.dll 
Password:
Failure adding assembly IronPython.dll to the cache: Strong name cannot be verified for delay-signed assembly
```

What does this mean? Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to add IronPython.dll to the GAC? That's really something that should either be done at a packaging level, or not at all. You can probably just copy IronPython.dll into the directory with your program and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build IronPython yourself?  Signing is kind of a PITA and you'll need to provide your own full key to get a real signature.  We do include the MS public key in the distribution but this can only be used for delay signing.  We do have delay signing turned on in the build which might result in a delay signed build even if you use a full key (I'm not sure what the compilers do here).

You can probably fully sign the assembly using sn or Mono's equivalent.  You also may be able to disable verification before installing in the GAC by using sn as well (this is what we when we develop IronPython).

Comment: I downloaded the IronPython. I find that mono has sn (mono strongname) utility. I tried -v -vf, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: In that case I have no clue what's going on :)