# Calling IronPython object from C# with mono

Tags: c#, mono, ironpython

I have the following IronPython code.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self, x, y):
        return (x+y)
```

I need to call this from C#, and I came up with the following code.

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using IronPython;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;

class Hello {
    public static void Main()
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptSource script = engine.CreateScriptFromSourceFile("myPythonScript.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

        script.Execute(scope);
    }
}
```

After copying IronPython.dll, I run the following command. (I tried to run gacutil, but I got some [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902032/gac-gacutil-not-working-with-ironpython-dll-on-mono).

```
 dmcs /r:IronPython.dll callipy.cs
```

But I got some error messages as follows.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
Missing method .ctor in assembly /Users/smcho/Desktop/cs/namespace/IronPython.dll, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/smcho/Desktop/cs/namespace/IronPython.dll mtoken: 0x0a000080
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
...
```

It seems like that IronPython needs Microsoft.Scipting.Core, but with mono I don't know what to do?

- Can C# run IronPython object on Mono? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IronPython is not a stand-alone DLL. It has some dependencies which should have been shipped with IronPython (they are included in the latest zipped distribution targeting .NET 2.0 -- see the [IronPython download page](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/release)):

```
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll
```

Make sure your project can find these DLLs (which it currently can't, which is why you're getting errors). I've never tried running IronPython on Mono, but it [should work](http://www.mono-project.com/Python).

Note that the IronPython release targeting .NET 4.0 doesn't include (or need) Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll and Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll, since their functionality has been merged into `System.Core`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737690/where-is-microsoft-scripting-core-dll/3737816#3737816) for more details.