# Embedding both IronRuby and IronPython

Tags: ironpython, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to run both ironruby and ironpython at the sample application.
I am getting an exception - 
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocat
ionException: Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.6.2': Could not load file or
 assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3
1bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file spe
cified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'M
icrosoft.Dynamic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364
e35' or one of its dependencies.

What to do? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902059/calling-ironpython-object-from-c-with-mono/3902170#3902170) to another similar question. IronPython and IronRuby depend on other libraries to work. One of these libraries is Microsoft.Dynamic, which your application seems unable to find. Make sure the DLL is in the same directory as your application (or in the GAC).

I believe this exception has nothing to do with using both IronPython and IronRuby in the same project; that is merely a coincidence.