# How to make Python.CreateEngine() work? - TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902170/1476739).
A simple example of calling IronPython from C# with MonoDev:

Python:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self, x, y):
        return (x+y)
```

C#:

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using IronPython;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;

class Hello {
    public static void Main()
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptSource script = engine.CreateScriptFromSourceFile("myPythonScript.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

        script.Execute(scope);
    }
}
```

I had several problems with the assemblies doing the same kind of examples. And now my problem is that each time the program tries to do:
`ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();`,
I get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.7.3': 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
IronPython.Runtime.ExtensionMethodSet ---> System.Exception: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
IronPython.Runtime.ExtensionMethodSet ---> System.Exception: 
Could not load type 'IronPython.Runtime.ExtensionMethodSet+AssemblyLoadInfo[]' 
from assembly 'IronPython, Version=2.7.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1'.
```

Following advice found in [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902170/1476739),
I've got to admit that I don't have Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging.dll because I don't know where it can be downloaded - it is not furnished with IronPython.
Could you tell me where I can get it and if it's the reason why I'm still stuck on this basic example?

Comment: Note the mismatch in version numbers.  This is the kind of error you'll get from that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm using IronPython 2.7.0 instead of the newest version, and everything is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
```

**should be**

```
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
```

`ScriptScope` is the **base class**.